# What is happening in this char* assignment? (comma operator with mixed types)

Tags: c, casting, char, quotes, assign

I'm working on some C code. In one of .c files I can see something like:

```
char* test = ("someChar", "someChar2", 3);
```

When I print out this variable, I get "3" on my screen.

What is happening in this part of code? Why do I get 3 as a result of printing out this char*? I am the most curious about this `("someChar", "someChar2", 3)` expression.

EDIT(after the issue has been resolved):

What made me scratch my head was also the fact, that there are two chars and one int in this expression. 
If we use `printf("%u", test)` we can get this number, but this code definitely doesn't look clean and I believe this is not an elegant way of assigning number to char*.

Comment: I think this isn't the code you're actually looking at.  If you set a char* to 3 you will most likely get a segmentation fault (or garbage output) when trying to print it.  Maybe it's "3" ?

Comment: @cleblanc: Or maybe the print is `printf("%d\n", test);`

Comment: @FredLarson Gotta love undefined behavior.

Comment: Something like is not a very precise definition. What is exactly the line and how is used `test` later?

Comment: Thank you @FredLarson - it indeed looks like the comma operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

Comment: Hellofa way to generate a pointer with address `3` via the *comma operator* and a parenthetical grouping. Attempting to access address `3` will come with a sudden surprise..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of `comma` operator & manual page of `operator` says *when in an expression if multiple comma are there* then solve from `Left to Right` but it considers **right most** argument.

In the statement

```
char* test = ("someChar", "someChar2", 3);
```

`test` get assigned with right most argument that is `3`. And now it looks like

```
char *test = 3;
```

since `test` is `char pointer` & it should initialize with *valid address* and `3` is not the valid address. So if you are just printing `test` like
`printf("%d\n",test);` that doesn't cause any error but that causes **undefined behavior**. And if you are going to dereference it like `*test` then your program get crashed(Seg. fault), this is one of possible scenario you should keep in mind while dealing with pointers.

Comment: printing a char* with `%d` is still undefined behavior

Comment: yup @cleblanc agree. I thought of writing it but forgot to put it. modified.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. To make things clear: the int value enclosed in my post in this assignment is not there by mistake. However I don't know why the original programmer put there this integer.

Comment: Welcome !! May be original programmer wanted to know whether one understood comma operator correctly or not. But you should be aware of all possible scenario specially with pointers.